# getIntent() method is undefined inside of onStartCommand() method of android service

Tags: android, service, android-intent, undefined, onstart

Does anyone know why my getIntent() method is undefined for the android service and inside of the onStartCommand() method?

```
   @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
super.onStartCommand(intent, startId, startId);

Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
filename = extras.getString("filename");


 return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the intent is passed as a parameter of the function...

```
onStartCommand(Intent intent, ...
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `getIntent()` method is of Activity not of Service. In Activity if you want to get the current Intent then you can call the `getIntent()` method to get the intent. In service the `onStartCommand()` method has the parameter intent already so you can fetch the extra data passed with the intent.

You are already getting `intent` object from the `onStartCommand()` method. check it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no `getIntent`() method in the `Service` class. You can use the intent argument as passed to `onStartCommand`